# place incoming call in queue and call agents with twilio

Tags: twilio

hello Im using Twilio and I want to put the caller on a queue. then call all the agents sequentially and if an agent pick up the phone I want to connect him with the caller that´s on a queue.

this is what I have so far but when I call I hear the agent voice mail. no waiting music.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
        <Say>Please wait while we connect you to the next available agent.</Say>
        <Enqueue>support</Enqueue>
        <Dial timeout="15" url="/call-queue">+100000000</Dial>
        <Dial timeout="15" url="/call-queue">+100000001</Dial>
        <Dial timeout="15" url="/call-queue">+100000002</Dial>
    </Response>
```

the response for /call-queue is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
        <Dial>
            <Queue>support</Queue>
        </Dial>
    </Response>
```

my goal is for the caller to wait in line with some music until one agent pickup the phone.

any ideas? is this the right approach? thank you!

**update:**

the caller gets added to the call like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Please wait while we connect you with the next agent.</Say>
    <Enqueue>support</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

then I make a REST call to call the agent

```
twilio.calls
    .create({
        url: "example.com/call-queue",
        from: myTwilioNumber,
        to: agentNumber
    })
    .then(call => console.log("twilio call sid", call.sid))
    .catch(error => console.log("twilio call error", error));
```

example.com/call-queue only returns

```
<Dial><Queue>support</Queue></Dial>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That's not the approach you want there. Following the `<Enqueue>` with `<Dial>` will just queue the caller and should not travel onto the next `<Dial>` until the caller leaves the queue again.

Since you have multiple agents, you might want to look into [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter) to achieve this. With TaskRouter you queue the incoming call and then a workflow that you define will attempt to dial your agents. Your agents can also choose to accept the incoming call or send it back to the queue. The TaskRouter call routing is also sensitive to agents already being calls and not trying to route to them.

Check out the documentation on [queueing Twilio calls with TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/twiml-queue-calls) to learn more.

Comment: hello! that makes sense.. any other way to achieve this without taskrouter? problem with this is it will require to enter data in twilio and I will do this dinamically. like .. if you call numer 1 you will have a list of possible agents, number 2. another list of possible agents but i will have many of these... and configuring on taskrouter will be painful. thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you can do it using regular `<Enqueue>` and the [REST API to make calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls) to your agents. There is a trade off between the amount of code you need to write versus the amount you need to configure workflows in TaskRouter.

Comment: I see. but is there a way do to client.calls.create sequentially? I don't want to call all agents at the same time.  just move to the next one  if call is not answered.

Comment: Yeah, you would need to set up to receive [the status callback webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#monitor-outbound-call-events) which is fired once the call is over with the call status sent as the `CallStatus` parameter in the body of the request. You can check that status to [see whether the call was answered or was busy or wasn't answered](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#parameters-sent-to-your-statuscallback-url) and then trigger a new call.

Comment: hey @philnash I´m still struggling with this: I´m doing <Enqueue>support</Enqueue> to put the caller on a queue and I´m doing twilio.calls.create({url: domain/call-queue}, ...) to call the agent (domain/call-queue just returns <Dial><Queue>support</Queue></Dial> but the caller get´s the mailbox of the agent. and the agent is not even getting the call goes straight to voicemail as missed call. not sure what´I´m doing wrong. (original question updated because is hard to read here) thanks again!

Comment: Right, you need to do a bit more than just return the `<Dial>` to the `<Queue>` in the call `url`. You probably want to involve [answering machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection) and checking whether the call was answered by a human, or a [call whisper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper) to avoid connecting the caller to voicemail.